# Finding base B'

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have B = {(0,2,1),(-2,2,1),(-1,2,1)} how can I find B' so $ x + [x]_B + [x]_{B'} = 0 $ 
(equlas zero vector). For every vector $ x \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Is $[x]_B$ the column-vector of $x$ with respect to the basis $B$?

Comment: Yes, B is basis and i have to find basis B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach is as follows: let $M_B$ denote the matrix whose columns are given by the vectors in $B$.  Then 
$$
[x]_B = M_B^{-1}x
$$
where $x$ denotes the column-vector for $x$ with respect to the standard basis.  What we're looking for, then, is a matrix $M_{B'}$ such that
$$
x + M_B^{-1}x  + M_{B'}^{-1}x = 0 \quad (\text{for all }x)\implies\\
(I + M_B^{-1}  + M_{B'}^{-1})x = 0 \quad (\text{for all }x)\implies\\
I + M_B^{-1}  + M_{B'}^{-1} = 0
$$
Solve the above for $M_{B'}$.